# How to add all existing Custom Taxonomy to Admin Menu Creations Interface?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, menus, taxonomy

How to add all existing Custom Taxonomy to Admin Menu Creations Interface?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For admin menu creation this document help you.

```
https://gist.github.com/nikolov-tmw/8698598
```

BEST Option for you :

**Appearance -> Menus -> Screen Options (Up-right corner) -> select Tags/Product tags**